# Trying to get a count of Diamonds dataset by quantile

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to do something I believe rather simple but seem to be having issues achieving it. I'm using the dataset "diamonds", which I've listed in the dput/structure commands here:

```
 dput(head(diamonds))
    structure(list(carat = c(0.23, 0.21, 0.23, 0.29, 0.31, 0.24), 
        cut = structure(c(5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Fair", 
        "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal"), class = c("ordered", 
        "factor")), color = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("D", 
        "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
        )), clarity = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("I1", 
        "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"), class = c("ordered", 
        "factor")), depth = c(61.5, 59.8, 56.9, 62.4, 63.3, 62.8), 
        table = c(55, 61, 65, 58, 58, 57), price = c(326L, 326L, 
        327L, 334L, 335L, 336L), x = c(3.95, 3.89, 4.05, 4.2, 4.34, 
        3.94), y = c(3.98, 3.84, 4.07, 4.23, 4.35, 3.96), z = c(2.43, 
        2.31, 2.31, 2.63, 2.75, 2.48)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I created a lvplot like this:

```
library(lvplot)
ggplot(diamonds,
       aes(x=cut,
           y=price))+
  geom_lv()+
  labs(title = "Cut of Diamonds by Price")
```

It looks like this:

[image: LVPLOT]

This gives a general feel of where the price distributes, but I'd like to see if there is a way to get a count per quantile. Basically, I want very specific counts for how many diamonds are sold at different prices (by quantile if possible).

Comment: Do you mean as a table or as a plot as in `ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + stat_ecdf()` or `ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) + stat_ecdf() +  facet_wrap( ~ cut, ncol = 1)`?

Comment: Oh to clarify I dont need another plot, just a count of each quantile in the console section.

Comment: Isn't the count just the quantile multiplied the total number? Given we have n diamonds, then the .25 quantile has .25 times n entries? Or if you do not want to think about rounding errors: For the 37%-quantile: `sum(diamonds$price < quantile(diamonds$price, probs = .37))`.

Comment: Thats a good one I didn't know. Is there a way to get a table of quantiles subdivided in some way? I'm thinking something where its grouped by percentage. Dont know if that makes any sense.

Comment: Well, it does not make that much sense for me. "Subdivided in some way" is kind of unspecific if the answer is to be given in code. I guess from your nickname that you may speak German as a first language. Unless the answer already given satisfies your need, you could consider forum.r-statistik.de

Comment: The person who just answered seemed to nail what I was looking for. Sorry if my explanation was poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your idea, you could create a varible that is the category for a general quantile of `price`, and compare with `cut`, here is an example with quartiles:

### Code

```
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
   #Create a variable with the general quartile, but you can change that
   mutate(price_quartile = cut(price,
                               quantile(price,seq(0,1,.25)),
                               include.lowest = TRUE,
                               labels = paste0("Q",1:4))) %>% 
   #Count observations by type of cut and price_quartile
   count(cut,price_quartile) %>% 
   #Calculate the percentage by cut
   group_by(cut) %>% 
   mutate(
      N = sum(n),
      p = 100*n/N
   )
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   cut [5]
   cut       price_quartile     n     N     p
   <ord>     <fct>          <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 Fair      Q1                88  1610  5.47
 2 Fair      Q2               462  1610 28.7 
 3 Fair      Q3               667  1610 41.4 
 4 Fair      Q4               393  1610 24.4 
 5 Good      Q1              1057  4906 21.5 
 6 Good      Q2              1087  4906 22.2 
 7 Good      Q3              1634  4906 33.3 
 8 Good      Q4              1128  4906 23.0 
 9 Very Good Q1              3129 12082 25.9 
10 Very Good Q2              2533 12082 21.0 
11 Very Good Q3              3369 12082 27.9 
12 Very Good Q4              3051 12082 25.3 
13 Premium   Q1              2907 13791 21.1 
14 Premium   Q2              3069 13791 22.3 
15 Premium   Q3              3504 13791 25.4 
16 Premium   Q4              4311 13791 31.3 
17 Ideal     Q1              6309 21551 29.3 
18 Ideal     Q2              6344 21551 29.4 
19 Ideal     Q3              4296 21551 19.9 
20 Ideal     Q4              4602 21551 21.4
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks champ!